# ios parse jsonresult how to iterate if it's not a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have this issue when I'm trying to parse my jsonresult that comes from a webapi. Take note, that whenver it would return a json result that looks like this:

```
[{"Id":0, "Name":Wombat, "Category":Animal}, 
{"Id":1, "Name":Trident, "Category":Object}]
```

This code works on that result:

```
NSArray *jsonresult = [WCFServiceRequest processWebApiGETRequestWithURL:url];

    if(jsonresult){
        for(id item in jsonresult){

            NSLog(@"item is %@", item);


            if([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                object.Id = [item objectForKey:@"Id"];
                object.name = [item objectForKey:@"Name"];
                object.category = [item objectForKey:@"Category"];

            }
        }
    }
```

But once it returns a none list result that looks like so:

```
{"Id":1, "Name":Trident, "Category":Object}
```

It would not go through the

```
if([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
```

Now if I take it out and just let it go straight to the assignment of the properties. The "item" variable that is returned from the jsonarray is the key eg: Id, Name, etc. Now I'm not sure how to properly iterate through the thing and assign it using keys. It seems like it's using indexes? Do I make another dictionary?

Comment: i have posted answer as per my best knowledge, let me know the insight if any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple to get the solution of it, when you are unaware about the result `DataType` simply `TypeCast` your object to `id` (A Generic DataType)

Store your json Response in `id`

```
id jsonresult = [WCFServiceRequest processWebApiGETRequestWithURL:url];

// Check whether Response is An Array of Dictionary
if([jsonresult isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSLog(@"it has multiple Dictionary so iterate through list");
    if(jsonresult){
        for(id item in jsonresult){
            NSLog(@"item is %@", item);                                
            if([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                object.Id = jsonresult[@"Id"];
                object.name = jsonresult[@"Name"];
                object.category = jsonresult[@"Category"];                    
            }
        }
    }
}
// Its Dictionary
else if([jsonresult isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSLog(@"It has only one dictionary so simply read it");
    object.Id = jsonresult[@"Id"];
    object.name = jsonresult[@"Name"];
    object.category = jsonresult[@"Category"];
}
```

Your response is `Dictionary` when you have only 1 Record in Result, and when you have more then 1 Record it will be an `Array`.